# 'Account' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

I was implementing django email verification.I'm facing an issue with 'Account' object has no attribute 'user'.

```
    'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from .models import Account
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
#verification email
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            username = email.split("@")[0]
            user = Account.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, username=username, password=password)
            user.phone_number = phone_number
            user.save()

            # USER ACTIVATION
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Please activate your account'
            
            verification_email_message = render_to_string('accounts/account_verification_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })

            to_email = email
            send_email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, verification_email_message, to=[to_email])
            send_email.send()

            messages.success(request, 'Registration Successful')
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)


def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            # messages.success(request,"You are now logged in.")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid login credentials')
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    messages.success(request,"You are logged out.")
    return redirect('login')

def activate(request):
    return
```

Comment: Could you kindly provide your Account model definition? When using default_token_generator.make_token, it requires a Django user object. I'd like to confirm if your Account model inherits from AbstractBaseUser. Could you share the relevant portion of your Account model, and if possible, include the error traceback you're encountering (From the console)? This information will help me assist you more effectively.

Answer (score -1):

Might it be due to the fact that you are using

```
'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
```

Instead of trying to access the primary key of the user?

Can consider trying:

```
'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user.pk)
```

Hope this helps!